# VBA - preventing Runtime Error 1004 - Method 'Union' error when using macro multiple times

Tags: vba, excel

I have a large macro which is editing a number of excel spreadsheets in a folder. At one stage of the macro, I am deleting any unused rows on the spreadsheet, including those rows which have no content, but due to the formatting appear in

```
lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

When I loop through the large macro for each spreadsheet, and reach the section of code, I encounter a Runtime Error 1004 - Method 'Union'. I have indicated the error below `'ISSUE HERE` where I am having difficulties assigning an Excel.Range variable. It works the first time, but then crashes the second. I have tried initialising the variable as Null following the loop, but that doesn't work. I also considered the possibility of dynamically changing the name of the variable, but I'm not sure how to do that either.

```
Dim Tempwks As Excel.Worksheet
        Dim Temprng As Excel.Range
        Dim Temprow As Long
        Dim XlastRow As Long

    ''''''''''''''''

        Set Tempwks = Excel.ActiveSheet
        XlastRow = lastRow

        With Tempwks

            For Temprow = 1 To XlastRow
                If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Rows(Temprow)) = 0 Then

                    If Temprng Is Nothing Then
                        Set Temprng = .Rows(Temprow)
                    Else

                    ' ISSUE HERE
                        Set Temprng = Excel.Union(Temprng, .Rows(Temprow))

                    End If

                End If
            Next Temprow

        End With

        If Not Temprng Is Nothing Then
            Call Temprng.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
```

EDIT -- Just to confirm, there is nothing wrong with the functionality of this code, it does what is required, it's just that when I run it multiple times, it comes up with the Runtime Error 1004 on the following specific line.

```
   Set Temprng = Excel.Union(Temprng, .Rows(Temprow))
```

If this macro ran again and the variable name changed from Temprng to Temprng2, it would work. The issue seems to be that once the variable has been Set once, it cannot be overwritten.

Comment: Run it again, then when it errors, do "Debug", and hover over XlastRow. Is it 0? Another guess: are you actually changing the sheet with each loop of your large macro? From what you've posted, it would do the same sheet (Activesheet) over and over again.

Comment: XlastRow shows 662, which is the correct number for the last row in the ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

Comment: Thank you very much! When you say "I have tried initialising the variable as Null following the loop", I assume you mean `Set Temprng = Nothing`?

Comment: What is the value of `TempRow` during the error? (Sorry to ask so many questions, I'm not sure what the problem is. Maybe someone more skilled than me will spot the problem and not need more info.)

Comment: Is the code above exactly the same as in your macro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see it right off the bat, so this doesn't directly solve your problem, but you can try this instead:

```
For Temprow = XlastRow To 1 Step -1
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Rows(Temprow)) = 0 Then
        .Rows(TempRow).Delete
    End If
Next TempRow
```

By going backwards through the rows, you don't have to worry about getting your counter messed up as the rows change numbers. And since you don't have to worry about that, you don't have to use `Union`.

EDIT: If you're just trying to get the TRUE last row, you can avoid all of this by using `Find`, i.e.

```
lngLastRow = sht.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, Lookat:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row
```

I prefer this method over any other, but you can find more [here](http://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/7/7/5-different-ways-to-find-the-last-row-or-last-column-using-vba). The find method is the last one on that page. You can also mess with the LookIn argument and change that to xlValues if that suits your needs better.

Comment: Great solutions thanks. I didn't consider removing the Union operator from the situation. I'll try it tomorrow when I get my laptop back.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the first passage of code works, but takes some time to process. Perhaps there is a faster option? The second method using .Find does not work, and still references the incorrect last row. There is no text in the extra rows, but some unusual formatting to blame. @PermaNoob

Comment: One thing that would make it faster would be setting the screenupdate to false and the calculation to manual at the beginning of the sub, then setting them back at the end. Also, I'm editing the answer to add something to the Find. Let me know if that works better for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is your problem, but I ran across a similar issue with the Union operation and discovered an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25147304).  The issue for me was using the correct context for the Union call, i.e., the Application from the worksheet that the ranges were on.  So in your case:

```
Set Temprng = Tempwks.Parent.Application.Union(Temprng, .Rows(Temprow))
```

Instead of:

```
Set Temprng = Excel.Union(Temprng, .Rows(Temprow))
```

Get the workbook from the worksheet (Tempwks.Parent) and the application from that workbook (Tempwks.Parent.Application).

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar error while building a chart using a MS Access VBA module to build a workbook. It turned out I wasn't explicate enough when I wrote (copied from macro recorder) the code. Error 1004 happens when you use the default object model for Excel (eg. Range("A1") vs Workbook(name).Sheet(name).Range or wsh.Range). In my case the problem line was for a chart object:

```vb
Dim xls as Excel.Application
Dim wsh as Worksheet
Dim cht as Chart
Dim rng1 as Range
Dim rng2 as Range
Dim rng3 as Range

''''code to set ranges and create chart object....

cht.SetSourceDate Source:=Range(xls.UNION(rng1, rng2, rng3).Address))
```

Correction:

```
cht.SetSourceDate Source:=wsh.Range(xls.UNION(rng1, rng2, rng3).Address))
```

You have to be carefull with macro recorder generated code using default object syntax. Make your code explicite to avoid 1004 errors.